# Prevent numbers from changing according to the locale in android

Tags: android, localization

When the user change the locale in device the numbers are also getting changed according  to the selected locale. This is causing NumberFormatException while performing mathematical operations and app is getting crashed. The code snippet which is causing the crash is given below.

```
public static double ToDataUnitMB(double _dataBytes){
double dDataBytes;

dDataBytes = Double.parseDouble(getDecimalFormat().format(_dataBytes / 1048576));

return dDataBytes; }
```

This code snippet is causing NumberFormatException and the value in _dataBytes is shown as "७२.४१". Can anyone help me to prevent the number from changing when user change the locale.

**Update**

I am getting the value "७२.४१" after performing the below operation `getDecimalFormat().format(_dataBytes / 1048576)`
So while parsing to Double it is showing numberFormatException

Comment: How do you assign `_dataBytes` ? That is where do you read it from?

Comment: @Gotiasits I am passing the value for _dataBytes  from another function. It represent the value contain the amount of data used by an app installed in bytes which i am fetching from the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're starting with raw `_dataBytes` you have several options how to format number independent of the locale.

### First Approach:

You can modify following snippet to your needs. It will give you the same output regardless of the user locale.

```
        String patern = "###.##"; //your pattern as per need
        Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);            
        decimalFormat.applyPattern(patern);
        double formatedDouble = Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(_dataBytes/(1024*1024f)));
```

Keep in mind that this method also makes grouping and decimal separators to be fixed, so that comma and dot will alway be used as, respectively, grouping separator and decimal separator.

---

### Second Approach:

If you do not strictly require Double you could generate formatted `String` with something similar to following method:

```
String generateFormatedFileSize(long _dataBytes) {
        String formatedFileSize = "";

        long bytes = _dataBytes;
        short unit = 1024;
        if (bytes < unit)
            formatedFileSize = bytes + " B";
        else {
            int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
            formatedFileSize = String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), "KMGT".charAt(exp - 1));               
        }

        return formatedFileSize;

    }
```

This formatting will be sensitive to grouping separator and decimal separator, but otherwise insensitive to Locale.

For Local that uses "US" numbering format, this will give you following output:

> 12.5 KB
>
> 5.3 B
>
> 8.0 MB

And for Local using "European" numbering format:

> 12,5 KB
>
> 5,3 B
>
> 8,0 MB

Off course, these two methods are not exclusive and you could use some mix of these approaches at different parts of the App.

Comment: It helps me in solving my issue, Thanks for your support